# How do I replace all the punctuation in a string with '\\W'?

Tags: r, regex

```
string = 'Hello, how are you?'
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Hello\\W how are you\\W
```

What I've done: Substituting all characters that are not alphanumeric with '\\W'

```
gsub('(\\W)+[^\\S]+','\\\\W',string,perl=TRUE)
[1] "Hello\\Whow are you?"
```

I'm not too sure why wasn't the question mark at the end of the sentence substituted with '\\W'and why was the first space being substituted. Could anyone help me out with this? Thank you!

Comment: You may also use `gsub('[\\p{P}\\p{S}]','\\\\W',string,perl=TRUE)`. The reason you could not replace the last symbol is that your regex matches at least 2 chars: 1+ non-word chars (`\W+`) and then at least one whitespace chars (`[^\\S]+`  = `\\s+`). In case you have to deal with Unicode texts, `gsub("(*UCP)[\\p{P}\\p{S}]","\\\\W",string,perl=TRUE)` might turn out handier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
gsub("[,?]", "\\\\W", string)
#[1] "Hello\\W how are you\\W"
```

If there are other characters, use `[[:punct:]]`

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "\\\\W", string)
#[1] "Hello\\W how are you\\W"
```

Comment: This works but the data that I'm dealing with contains a variety of symbols, not just ',' and '?'. :(

Comment: @OinkOink  You can use `[[:punct:]]` instead of `[,?]`

Comment: Didn't think of that! Thank you so much!!